# Show Different Html Forms by Clicking on Specific Links within One Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

i has file within my wordpress theme this file contains the signin, signup, lostpasswors and reset password forms with the required php codes. and in my header i have two buttons created by bootstrap codes us follow.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="user-notlogged-in" class="pull-right btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><a class="signin" href="<?php echo bloginfo('url') ?>/login"><?php _e('Sign In'); ?></a></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a class="signup" href="<?php echo bloginfo('url') ?>/login"><?php _e('Sign up'); ?></a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my `login-register.php` file i have above forms like below

```
<div id="signin-form">
</div>
<div id="signup-form">
</div>
<div id="resetpass-form">
</div>
<div id="newpass-form">
</div>
```

this link below contains full code in my `login-register.php` file
[login-register.php](http://www.gulfup.com/?3vsj2K)
my questions

1. i want when click on Sign In link only show me signin-form
2. i want when click on Sign Up link only show me signup-form
3. i want when i click on Lost Password? Link only show me resetpass-form
4. i want when send me reset password mail and i clcik on reset password link only show me newpass-form

Comment: I want to win the lottery, but I wont get any help here, and neither will you with a question like that! **This is not where you come to get your development done for free** Show the code you have tried, or try some research and then develop some code, if its not quite perfect then you will get some help.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question? I don't see any questions. Just a list of requirements and a strong "do this for me for free" slant.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No need to be rude.  That being said, I agree that this question is too vague.

Comment: @Brian I didnt think I was being rude, a little forceful possibly! I did afterall say help was available for the right type of question.

Comment: Why my question too vauge??? i have the php file in my wordpress theme contains the register, login, losts password and restepassword forms i want when i click on singin button only show me login from and don't show other forms DO THIS QUESTION VAUGE???

Comment: i have the login teamplate in my wordpress theme this template contains four forms when any one click on Sign In button show all four forms but i want when any one click on Sign In form only show singin-form and wehn clcik on Sign Up button only show singup-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is some simple jquery. Try something like...

```
onclick=$('#signin-form').show();
```

Comment: yes my brother? but if you can see my full code and help me i want solve all my problems

Comment: i have the login teamplate in my wordpress theme this template contains four forms when any one click on Sign In button show all four forms but i want when any one click on Sign In form only show singin-form and wehn clcik on Sign Up button only show singup-form

Comment: @Brian See, not vague at all. He set out the requirements and now he want somone to code it, test it and deliver it for free!

Comment: I've given you the tools to solve the problem, but I'm not going to write all the code for you. If you have more specific questions feel free to ask.

Comment: i agree give me the tools

Comment: He has already given you all the information you should need to produce the code yourself

Comment: thank you it is work but in wordpress theme within wp-login.php file done this by using switch loop

Answer (score 0):

there is one Way i hope it will help You.
You can Use Jquery for Show And hide forms.

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/ffor00ps/3/`
```

Try it may be this will help to solve your problem